# How to extract certificate subject attribute values in ASN.1 format?

Tags: node.js, x509certificate, asn.1

using openssl command directly on prompt I can print the subject of a certificate directly to ASN.1 format:

```
openssl x509 -subject -noout -nameopt rfc2253 -nameopt dump_all -nameopt oid -nameopt sep_multiline -in mycertificate.cer
```

The certificate is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The output of the command above is:

```
subject=
0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=#132437323138653161662D313935662D343262352D613434622D386337383238343730663561
2.5.4.97=#132A4F464242522D37346539323964392D333362362D346438352D386261372D633134366338363761383137
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=#1302554B
2.5.4.15=#131450726976617465204F7267616E697A6174696F6E
2.5.4.5=#130E3433313432363636303030313937
2.5.4.3=#1303747070
2.5.4.10=#13134F70656E2042616E6B696E672042726173696C
2.5.4.7=#13064C4F4E444F4E
2.5.4.8=#1302524A
2.5.4.6=#13024252
```

I'm trying to get a similar output using NodeJS, but without success... I've tried X509Certificate from crypto, ans1js, pk1js, but haven't success.

Is there a way to get the values using Node?

Thx

Comment: can you paste the certificate you are trying to parse?

Comment: Have you tried parsing the output of [`x509.subject`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#x509subject)?

Comment: @YaFred I edited the post including o certificate

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes, but x509.subject doesn't output in ASN.1 format.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by ASN.1 format. Here is your certificate as an ASN.1 value https://pastebin.com/QtBCrkwH ... you'll see that your openssl output is not so great after all. I think you should explore the x509.subject (I'll try it myself). Take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-x509-subject-property/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the best way is to use https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#x509subject

The output is a string and is perfectly parsable

This is an ordered collection of key/values ('=' separating key from value and '\n' separating each key/value)

The ouput for your certificate is:

```
C=BR
ST=RJ
L=LONDON
O=Open Banking Brasil
CN=tpp
serialNumber=43142666000197
businessCategory=Private Organization
jurisdictionC=UK
organizationIdentifier=OFBBR-74e929d9-33b6-4d85-8ba7-c146c867a817
UID=7218e1af-195f-42b5-a44b-8c7828470f5a
```

This is the human readable form of the component ***subject*** of your certificate encoded [here](https://pastebin.com/QtBCrkwH) as an ASN.1 value (search for ***subject rdnSequence***)

Note that ***ASN.1 format*** is not a thing ...